# What's the difference between restore iPhone through iTunes and erase phone through Find My (suppose you don't have backups anyway)

Tags: iphone, itunes, restore, find-my-iphone, find-my

So today I'm in a situation where my iPhone is disabled after too many attempt of wrong passcode which by some research seems I need to start over and erase all my data. Which isn't an issue as I basically synced everything through Google Services. And since I'm syncing using Google, it also meant I don't have backups through Apple services, whether local iTunes or iCloud.

Now after some finding, I found (majority) of articles telling me just install iTunes and restore the phone, while it seems some suggests you could also use the erase phone option with the Find My service. Which makes me wonder, what's the difference between those two (suppose I have no backup to restore from)? Since it'll be easier for me to just erase it through my old iPhone's Find My app instead of getting a laptop and install iTunes. Would it be better for one approach than another?

One thing I'm concerned is there's seems to be an activation lock which is enabled when you erase phone through Find My, which I'm not sure if it'll ask Apple ID's password? Or the phones original passcode? Cause ultimately, I don't have the correct passcode for the device (as I perhaps misclick the wrong number during resetting my passcode, and now I can't get the right one...), so if it's asking for the latter, Find My wouldn't work in my case.